# Using requests with python 2.6 to connect to ipv6 address

Tags: python, python-requests, ipv6

I am using python 2.6 and I try to connect to ipv6 website with requests and I always get 400

I am sure the ipv6 is setting correctly because I can curl it.  It is just inside python/requests that I cannot connect to..

Can someone help please

Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like your python version is ver old. Has it configured with `--enable-ipv6` support while being installed?

Comment: Take a look at what happens on the wire. Maybe something wrong is happening to the host header.

Comment: Thanks for all the advices but here is more info:
if in my /etc/hosts I add the mapping to from ipv6 to the name then use that dns entry to connect , it will works...But if I explicitly use the numeric format of the ipv6 it never work...

Comment: Did you put the IP in square brackets? `requests.get('http://[::1]/')`

Comment: upgrade python to 3.6